# jQuery ajax speed vs direct access speed

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I have a web service written using the Pyramid framework and a frontend written using jQuery and jQuery Mobile. What I have noticed is that some of the Ajax calls take about 5-10 times longer to complete using the Ajax method over directly going to the URL in a browser.

My Ajax code looks like this, shortened for brevity:

```
$.ajax({
      url:address,
      dataType:'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data)
      {
          Parsing and other stuff that takes some time...
      }});
```

Now, I fire about 10 of these at once, to different URLs, which could be the reason for the slower response, but if I fire just one at a time it is still about 3 times slower. (30ms vs 90ms). I have tried using the waitress in Pyramid, as well as mod_wsgi (1 process, 4 threads) with about the same result.

My question is: where is the overhead coming from? Pyramid? Web server? jQuery? jQM? .ajax()? What can I do, if anything to decrease the request time?

Edit: Switching between JSON and JSONP has little effect, but the further testing has shown that the time is very variable (50ms to 100ms) from test to test. However, the direct access to the service through browser is always 30ms +/- 1 ms.

I have tested this with Firebug, Chrome Web Dev tool, and Fiddler with similar results. When replicating one of the requests in Fiddler, I get a similar result to that of going directly to the resource in a browser.

Here is a screencap from Firebug of a run where I'm purposefully trying to make it slower by running the 9 calls 5 times each: http://s16.postimage.org/n6t5z1ow5/ajax_Cap.png hope that can give some more hints. Grey is "blocking", purple is "waiting".

Comment: What do you see in Firebug? Did you log the time at any step? The data is in your side, not our...

Comment: In both Firebug and Chrome I see that most of the time is spent "Waiting" in both ajax and direct access cases.

Comment: It could be some sort of overhead associated with using `jsonp`. This test shows that it's a bit slower than normal `json`: http://jsperf.com/ajax-jsonp-vs-ajax-json

Comment: Also, is the same Pyramid process serving both the page and the jsonp?

Comment: I will test by switching to json for server that runs both so the crossdomain/jsonp issue could be eliminated. The result is about the same for Pyramid provided JS or some other web server JS. (If I get your meaning...)

Comment: I believe we need to know more about your measuring methods. I can suggest using a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and examining all requests with that. I suppose Firebug should be just as good, but... well, it won't hurt to take Firefox out of the equation. Anyhow, Fiddler will just show you the raw request times, and you can also throughly inspect and _replicate_ any request made, so you can determine whether the slowdown is on the browser side or the server side.

Comment: what is slower? the overall response time? or the time to first byte?

Comment: @TomWillis The amount of time taken from the request is fired, until it completes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is the crossdomain/jsonp option - as this is a 'fake' ajax request to get around browser security restrictions.

What JQuery is doing here is creating a script element with the source set to the URL you supplied in the call (and some other stuff, wrapping the returned data in a function call), so almost certainly there is some weirdness / slowness going on. If I remember right, the browser actually blocks script execution while it's loading script blocks too...?

You could try to get around this by including in your service a  ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea) header set to '*' (allows all access), and taking out all your 'crossdomain' stuff.

Comment: I tried to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to '*', but this had little effect as far as I can tell. One big difference between dataType:'jsonp' and dataType:'json' is that when running very many requests, the previous requests don't seem to block the next requests as shown in the image, but the result is the same, the later requests just begin later.

Comment: after you have set the header, and checked that it is coming through, set crossdomain to false, and try it again.

Comment: Just checked, and it is indeed coming through. There is no noticable difference however. I also tried changing the renderer from jsonp to json in the Pyramid views, but without noticable changes.